# Know domain name called from docker-compose download step

Tags: docker, docker-compose

how could I know which domain are used for the download of my docker image ?

I need it cause the server I'm using only a allow a specific list of domain name for outside traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using wireshark to capture every dns package, and look up the domain name present.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull an image by simply using its name (e.g.`docker pull postgres`), the image probably comes from Docker Hub. Otherwise the registry you're pulling the image from will be listed (e.g. `docker pull quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1`)

[Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#description)